# Creating activitybar Icons for VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have been trying numerous editors, from Inkscape, to online converters, to MS store apps, etc.

All I'm trying to do is find an easy way to create either transparent PNG files or SVG files for the activitybar icon inside of VS Code for an extension I'm working on.

Everything I've tried either totally warps the dimensions of what I create and seems to blow the image way up inside the activity bar, even though the files I'm saving as PNG are all 128px x 128px with 32 bit depth, same as another that ships with examples from https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/tree-view-sample

What I see in VS Code after specifying the path in the extension package.json:

[image]

What I am trying to get it to look like:

[image]

I've tried using SVG viewer plugins for VS Code as well, and sometimes the SVG's I've used don't even show up, even though an item does exist in the activity bar when I hover over the position it should be in.

Any modicum of help would be appreciated.

Comment: According to the hover docs they're 24x24: https://i.imgur.com/ZCGUbM1.png A png of that size works for me.

Comment: Cheers @Gama11 will give that a go. I was probably looking at the wrong documentation

Comment: Yep, absolutely worked. Thanks again